# Clean URLS on Hiawatha

Tags: drupal, web-server

I am using the Hiawatha webserver and running Drupal on a FastCGI PHP server.
The Drupal site is using imagecache and it requires either private files or clean URLs.
The issue I am having with clean URLs is that requests to files are being rewritten into index.php as well.

My current config is:

```
UrlToolkit {
    ToolkitID = drupal
    RequestURI exists Return
    Match (/files/*) Rewrite $1
    Match ^/(.*) Rewrite /index.php?q=$1
}
```

The above does not work.

---

Drupal's apache set up is:

```
<Directory /var/www/example.com>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
UrlToolkit {
    ToolkitID = drupal
    RequestURI exists Return
    Match ^/(.*)\?(.*) Rewrite /index.php?q=$1&$2
    Match ^/(.*) Rewrite /index.php?q=$1
}
```